# PhoneGap Facebook plugin for Android

Tags: jquery-plugins, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I am using Cordova 2.7.0 for building an app which wants to post some data on to the facebook wall.
I tried with [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin).I am getting the errors in the Java files. I followed all the steps in tutorial.Not able to proceed further.:(
Please let me know the right phonegap/Jquerymobile plugin for facebook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @surya- add some more details , like for android or ios you developing  app. show your error log here .

Comment: Mine is an Hybrid app, I just tried this plugin for Android.Here is what I am facing issues.

Comment: i use same plugin with cordova-2.7.0 it works for me perfectly.